# Sterilizing Mason Jar for Oat Yogurt?

Tags: fermentation, yogurt, oat-milk

Making homemade Oat Milk into Yogurt for the first time! Unfortunately I made an oversight and pulled a Mason Jar out of the cabinet and just washed it with soap and hot water let it mostly air dry, then added my cooled down mixture of Oat milk (boiled to 180f + tapioca starch & coconut oil), let it cool and then added probiotics. Planing on letting it go for 12-24hr.

Is this unsafe and am I talking a large risk here by letting this culture without technically sterilizing the mason jar? I assume this can't be as risky as animal derived milk, but I have no idea, and don't want to cultivate bad bacteria or something toxic.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly risky.  In general, any bacteria or fungi that will hurt you will also cause the yogurt to turn visibly and smellably bad.

Comment: Fair enough, that’s sort of what I figured with the yogurt being pasteurized to 180, having washed the Jar with soap and the ingredients all being shelf safe and not dairy product. Out of abundance of caution I will sterilize the jars in the future though. Also the Oat milk yogurt is quite good and I recommend it!

Comment: Mainly, sterilization is a way to make sure that you don't get wild bacteria or yeasts that would ruin your batch, rather than out of health concerns.

Comment: I know very serious things like botulism are a concern with not sterilizing, however it's not entirely clear if the really bad stuff is a concern with a 12-48hr period in vegan yogurt and also given that this isn't fundamentally canning in the first place. In retrospect this is what I should've been looking into in the first place

Comment: Yogurt is a high-acid food, making it very low risk for botulism.